# How to close the One-Tap hint when user logs in with another method?

Tags: javascript, google-identity

I managed to implement the relatively new One-Tap sign-up/sign-in flows, following the get started guide [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/overview). I also have other login methods working on the same project (facebook login and email/password login). When the user logs in using one of these other methods, the One-Tap hint inviting the user to login with Google stays there, in the middle of my logged-in experience, as the hint was added to the page before the user was identified. In my login flow, I don't reload the page. I just replace/show/hide stuff on it. How can I close that Google invitation when the user decides to login with another method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can call this method, [source](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/retrieve-hints#request_sign-in_hints)

```
googleyolo.cancelLastOperation().then(() => {


// Credential selector closed.

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It is really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

This has changed to the following -

```
google.accounts.id.cancel();
```

[Sign In With Google JavaScript API reference  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.cancel)

Comment: Hi Josh, Do you know how to close google one tap bottom sheet programmatically in android  ?

Comment: @Rummy I'm sorry I don't.